# Serial Key for JRuby application running on tomcat

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, tomcat, jruby

I have a RoR3 application which I converted to jruby and used warbler to create a war. It is deployed in Windows XP (yes, believe me).

The client needs some kind of serial key to make sure that if someone steals his source code it cannot be deployed anywhere else. 
I can do a keygen or something like that and generate a key based on the MAC but I am not sure what to do with that. Does anyone have an idea? I am lost with this.

Maybe I can develop a process that executes on startup of Tomcat and doesn´t deploy the application if it doesn´t find the serial. I dont know. Please help.

Comment: Nobody on SO can possibly help you with this.  You haven't provided any useful information.  You have "a RoR3 application" - which one? "The client" -- which client? What kind of key? Do you have the client source? Are you trying to circumvent the key requirement?

Comment: Hi Jim. Sorry if you think that I am not clear. The key requirement is just "I want some kind of key to make sure that anybody steals my code". I need some advice or alternative to do this. By the client I mean the person who hired my company. It is a typical RoR 3 deployed on a tomcat using JRuby and warbler. Thanks.

Comment: Tony, you may want to edit your question. A title more like "How do I protect my application with a license key?" and then more details on what type of app it is and how it is deployed by your user(s) would be useful.

Comment: Oh, and if someone steals the source there's nothing you can do. Best thing is to prevent access to the source to begin with. Use the `compiled` option of warbler so you're not distributing the source, only the compiled .class files.

Answer (score 0):

Once upon a time when I used to work with Rails I used [Ruby Encoder](http://rubyencoder.com/)  for a client with similar requirements. It could tie a build to a particular network interface, CPU, etc. IIRC it only worked with MRI ruby though. Maybe you could investigate `jrubyc`?